# Binding на сущность, на которую нет ни у кого ссылки

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

**Доброго времени суток.**

Есть 2 сущности в дереве - Drive и Disk.

Для вывода в дереве(чтобы не морочаться пока) сделал 
Drive в котором есть свойство Disk[] c именем TreeItems.

Для удобного доступа к моему Disk(он всего может быть один) есть поле Disk.

Далее, при обнулении

```
TreeItems[0] = null;
```

И вызова `OnPropertyChanged("TreeItems")`... ветвь дерева продолжает быть привязана к тому объекту(из системы он не удалился), но при этом связей в родителях нет(тобишь в системе Disk и Drive не связаны, а вот в интерфейсе все еще).
В момент обновления(`OnPropertyChanged("TreeItems");`) в коллекции один элемент равный Null.

**Вопрос:** что я делаю не так и почему не срабатывает привязка так, как я задумал?

**Пример кода:**

**Сама коллекция:**

```
public DiskDVM[] TreeItems { get { return treeItems; } }
```

В момент обновления(`OnPropertyChanged("TreeItems");`) в коллекции один элемент равный Null.

XAML:
**Шаблон для Disk**

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DVMs:DiskDVM}" x:Key="CartridgeDataTemplate" >

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="True"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="False"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

            <Image Width="15" Height="15" Source="pack://application:,,,/images/Catridge/catridge.png"></Image>

            <TextBox Text="{Binding StrTitle}"></TextBox>

        </StackPanel>

    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

**Шаблон для Drive:**

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DVMs:DriveDVM}" x:Key="DriveDataTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" >

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="True"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="False"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

                <Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/images/Drive/drive.png"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StrTitle}" Foreground="{Binding IsActive,Converter={StaticResource IsActiveToColorFontConverter}}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>


    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: А какого типа `TreeItems`? Почему не `ObservableCollection<...>`?

Comment: А как вы хотите, чтобы привязка сработала? Удалился элемент? Так элемент не удалился, вы просто его значение обнулили. Всё равно что удалять `TextBox` очисткой `Text`. Значения исчезли? Так они и не исчезнут просто так: привязки больше нет и новых данных брать неоткуда, а от null таких данных не получить, поэтому остаются старые.

Comment: Это не работает, т.к. вы пользуетесь `INPC`, фреймворк проверяет свойство - ссылка не изменилась, значит ничего обновлять не нужно. Для оповещения об изменениях элементов в коллекции нужно использовать `INCC`, но его не так просто реализовать правильно, поэтому просто используйте готовый класс `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Можно попробовать изменить ссылку `TreeItems = (DiskDVM[])Array.Clone(TreeItems)`, но это грязно. Вы скопируете целиком весь массив, WPF его весь заново перечитает и заново всё с нуля построит - слишком много накладных расходов для изменения всего одного элемента коллекции, поэтому гораздо эффективнее использовать `INCC`

Comment: @VladD потому что я хочу, чтобы в одном Drive был только один Disk(я таким образом ограничиваю массив).

Comment: @John у меня ссылается на TreeItems. Я вызывают OnPropertyChanged("TreeItems") и по идее он должен полностью обновить все. 
В том то и дело, что привязка остается. Я могу менять значения и они меняются в объекте

Comment: @Андрей дело в том, что ObservableCollection нельзя ограничит в количестве элементов. Но я оповещаю View об изменении коллекции с помощью OnPropertyChanged("TreeItems"). По идее он должен обновить привязанное свойство. Тобишь я говорю, что ItemsSource нужно обновить...

Comment: @Arantler, вы говорите View, что изменилась ссылка на коллекцию, он смотрит - а она не изменилась и, соответственно, ничего не обновляет. Это так не работает, не просто так сделали именно 2 разных интерфейса `INPC` и `INCC`

Comment: Ну и непонятно, что вам мешает ограничить `ObservableCollection` вручную - напишите простейшую оболочку...

Comment: @Андрей не изменилась ссылка - ну так она и при ObservableCollection не меняется(меняются колличество элементов внутри).

Про ограничит: я так делаю, просто хочу разобраться почему не работает как я в начале пробовал, ибо не понимания этого, я возможно не понимаю ключевую особенность Binding, c которой раньше не встречался.

Comment: @Arantler, ObservableCollecion реализует INotifyCollectionChanged, который как раз оповещает об изменениях ВНУТРИ коллекции, а массив не оповещает. Что здесь не понятного? Смотрите у вас есть закрытый шкаф с полками, на шкафу написано "Шкаф №1". Вы убираете с нижней полки носки и говорите наблюдателю: в этой комнате шкаф изменился. Наблюдатель заходит в комнату и видит, что шкаф тот же самый "Шкаф №1", думает что ложная тревога и уходит. Поэтому это не работает. Что бы это работало необходимо сказать наблюдателю, что изменилось содержимое нижней полки шкафа "Шкаф №1". А массив этого не умеет.

Comment: Я вам говорил как это можно исправить: `TreeItems = (DiskDVM[])Array.Clone(TreeItems)`, но это перебор. Это тоже самое, что взять всё содержимое шкафа "Шкаф №1" и переложить в "Шкаф №2" по тем же полкам, потом "Шкаф №1" выбросить, а на его место поставить "Шкаф №2". Тогда наблюдатель придет и увидит полностью новый шкаф, поэтому он будет изучать его содержимое заново полностью. Но это плохое решение, как я уже говорил.

Comment: @Андрей как раз это понятно. Но я оповещаю об не изменении внутри массива, а вообще о том, что массив нужно обновить во View(заново). Я с помощью OnPropertyChanged("TreeItems") и говорю, что нужно во View обновить масси(т.е полностью переписать).

Comment: @Андрей я теперь понял, почему так не работает. При вызове OnPropertyChanged("TreeItems") он смотрит на изменения коллекции(в любом случае), но эта логика не во View, а в самой коллекции. А т.к я использую такой массив, то у него просто нет механизмов сказать, что я изменился. Так?

Comment: @Андрей если бы эта логика(просмотра изменения) была во View или в другом месте, оно бы сработало, но коллекция эту информацию сама выдает.

Comment: @Андрей ObservableCollection это умеет делать(в параметрах вызова события есть навигационные значения),а [] просто изменяется и не знает, что изменяется.

Comment: Если вам нужно определенное строго заданное количество ячеек, в которые вы будете помещать в том числе `null` - вы можете написать небольшую обертку с одним свойством `Value` (обвешенным `INPC`) и поместить эти обертки в массив, вот тогда будет работать именно так как вам нужно. У вас в ячейках массива будут лежать всегда одни и те же элементы, но они будут оповещать о смене в них значения.

Comment: @Андрей я так и сделал еще до задания вопроса. Меня интересовало, почему способ из вопроса у меня не сработал.

Comment: @Arantler, ну, я надеюсь, теперь вы поняли почему? Если нет - прочитайте [этот комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748737/binding-на-сущность-на-которую-нет-ни-у-кого-ссылки?noredirect=1#comment1152409_748737) еще раз

Comment: @Андрей да, понял вроде. [] не может сказать, что изменился. А View отслеживает изменения не сам, а обновляет, основываясь на информации, которую предоставляет коллекция. А если она не может предоставить, то и обновления не будет.